# Node.js: Backup MySQL database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I want to backup a MySQL database. Is it possible to do it in Node.js? If not, what is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

simple way without libs:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child = exec(' mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql');
```

Comment: Assuming you have mysql client tools installed.

Comment: using this i can do with only one database what if I've to dump all database

Comment: Do I need to just replace bracket data or the whole? Like -p[password_here] or -p password_here

Answer (score 11):

You can use exec method as described by [siavolt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30921752/3263601) it is simple but not the "best way" as requested by the question.

The best and efficient way in case if you care about your system memory and CPU and performance or if you have a big database is to use `spawn` along with the stream, so here is the "best way" in my opinion:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('dumpfilename.sql');

var mysqldump = spawn('mysqldump', [
    '-u',
    'DB_USER',
    '-pDB_PASSWORD',
    'DB_NAME',
]);

mysqldump
    .stdout
    .pipe(wstream)
    .on('finish', function () {
        console.log('Completed')
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err)
    });
```

If your database doesn't have a password you can remove `'-pDB_PASSWORD',` code.

Remember to replace `DB_XXX` with actual values, i.e. `'root'` instead of `'DB_USER'`, or `'-pXXXXXXXX'` instead of `'-pDB_PASSWORD'`.

Comment: this worked for me when I changed the 'spawn' line to; var mysqldump = spawn('mysqldump', [
    '-u',
    'DB_USER',
    '-pDB_PASSWORD',
    'DB_NAME',
]);

Comment: note that this didn't work for me with async/await. I needed to use `mysqldump.stdout.pipe(wstream)` and `for await ( const data of mysqldump.stdout) { // filler }`

Answer (score 10):

simple and powerfull way

```
npm install mysqldump
```

Run :

```
import mysqldump from 'mysqldump';
// or const mysqldump = require('mysqldump')
 
// dump the result straight to a file
mysqldump({
    connection: {
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '123456',
        database: 'my_database',
    },
    dumpToFile: './dump.sql',
});
```

File Path:

write absolute path example (check into G Disk Drive)

```
dumpToFile:'G:\dump.sql'
```

or
Relative path

```
dumpToFile:'.\dump.sql' (root of project directory)
```

Comment: Clean and efficient!

Answer (score 5):

You could backup mySQL Databases utilizing node-cron, I like this because it ensures that your DB backup will always run regardless of the OS that you are hosting your Node App.

```
npm install node-cron
npm install moment (only for file name formatting)
```

@app.js (the file that you serve your Node App)

```
const cron = require('node-cron')
const moment = require('moment')
const fs = require('fs')
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn

// You can adjust the backup frequency as you like, this case will run once a day
cron.schedule('0 0 * * *', () => {
// Use moment.js or any other way to dynamically generate file name
  const fileName = `${process.env.DB_NAME}_${moment().format('YYYY_MM_DD')}.sql`
  const wstream = fs.createWriteStream(`/Path/You/Want/To/Save/${fileName}`)
  console.log('---------------------')
  console.log('Running Database Backup Cron Job')
  const mysqldump = spawn('mysqldump', [ '-u', process.env.DB_USER, `-p${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}`, process.env.DB_NAME ])

  mysqldump
    .stdout
    .pipe(wstream)
    .on('finish', () => {
      console.log('DB Backup Completed!')
    })
    .on('error', (err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
})

...
...
app.listen()
```

You could hardcode all your DB_USER & DB_PASSWORD but i find it is best practice to read from a .env file, so it can work in both Development & Production environment

```
ENVIRONMENT = development
LOCAL_API = http://api.url
GOD_TOKEN = godtokenauthmenow
DB_HOST = 127.0.0.1
DB_NAME = myDatabaseName
DB_USER = myUsername
DB_PASSWORD = myPassword
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec(' mysqldump -u root -p dbname > fileName.sql');
```

This worked for me

Comment: this will prompt for password every time the command runs. what if i want to automate the process?

Comment: doesn't correct answer already have this included in the explanation?

Answer (score -1):

```
const {exec} = require('child_process');

exec('mysqldump --user=root --password=yourPassword --result-file=D:/dbBackup.sql --databases database_name);
```

Comment: You should provide some explanation along with supporting information for your answer